# Jupyter gives IOError for .text file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter notebook to import some data from a text file.

The folder from which I have imported the notebook has another file, `data.txt` but when I try to use the `loadtxt()` module, the following error appears:

```
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-a129a96139d0> in <module>()
----> 1 our_data = loadtxt("data.txt")
IOError: data.txt not found.
```

I looked for a solution and the manual in the notebook stated that the *file may not be in the same directory or folder as your notebook.*

I checked twice and found that the folder on my computer contains both the notebook and the `data.txt` file in the same location.

What is the issue?

Comment: If it's windows, check the file name after enabling file name extension in view.

Answer (score 1):

The file is simply not in the folder of the output of this code

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

You need to either put the `data.txt` file in this folder or load the file with a path the points to the file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `loadtxt()` method is from `numpy`, so you should add`import numpy as np` and use it as `np.loadtxt()`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would expect a different error if that was the issue, something like loadtxt not defined

Comment: I did import all the relevant modules using `%pylab inline`

Comment: Right... In that case, how about trying using `np.genfromtxt()` instead? Or just include the absolute path of your `data.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using a full path instead of just data.txt?

Maybe the current directory for jupyter is not where the notebook is.

Or you could try printing the current directory, or current directory contents like this to be sure:

```
import os;print(os.listdir("."))
```